# Working with libdpkg in C

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, dpkg

I looked into the "dpkg-query" source-code and tried to get the list of installed packages.

It compiles, but when i try to run i get the fault at modstatdb_open() function.

```
#define LIBDPKG_VOLATILE_API 1
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dpkg/macros.h>
#include <dpkg/dpkg.h>
#include <dpkg/dpkg-db.h>
#include <dpkg/pkg-array.h>
#include <dpkg/debug.h>
#include <dpkg/pkg-list.h>

void main()
{
   struct pkg_array array;

   modstatdb_open(msdbrw_readonly | msdbrw_available_readonly);

   pkg_array_init_from_db(&array);

   printf("%d\n",array.n_pkgs);

   pkg_array_destroy(&array);
   modstatdb_shutdown();
}
```

Segmentation fault (core dumped)

What is wrong there?

Comment: You should call `standard_startup();` and `filesdbinit();` before `modstatdb_open()`

Comment: and standard_shutdown(); after all

Comment: Tahnk you so much. It works now.

Comment: will anybody make an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working version.
It has to use dpkg_program_init(char *progname); before all.

```
#define LIBDPKG_VOLATILE_API 1

#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dpkg/dpkg.h>
#include <dpkg/dpkg-db.h>
#include <dpkg/pkg-array.h>


void main()
{
    struct pkgset *set;
    struct pkginfo *inf;
    struct pkg_array array;

    dpkg_program_init("a.out");
    modstatdb_open(msdbrw_available_readonly);

    pkg_array_init_from_db(&array);
    printf("Number of packages in local database: %d\n",array.n_pkgs);

    inf = pkg_db_find_singleton("kate");
    printf("status code of package: %d\n", inf->status);// 7 means installed

    dpkg_program_done();
}
```